# Local Report Viewer 11 (RDLC) doesn't process applied parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, rdlc

In Report Viewer 11 (VS2012) WinForms, we encountered a strange problem regarding report parameters while in local RDLC reports.

We have setup a local report that consumes a report parameter and shows this to the user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" 
        xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

[...]

<ReportParameters>
  <ReportParameter Name="TestValue">
    <DataType>String</DataType>
    <Prompt>ReportParameter1</Prompt>
  </ReportParameter>
</ReportParameters>

[...]

<Textbox Name="TestValueTextBox">
      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
      <Paragraphs>
        <Paragraph>
          <TextRuns>
            <TextRun>
              <Value>=Parameters!TestValue.Value</Value>
              [...]
            </TextRun>
          </TextRuns>
          <Style>
</Report>
```

In code, we apply the parameter like here:

```
this.View.reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(reportRdlc);

ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("TestValue", "TEST");

this.View.reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp);
```

The report viewer does not apply the value but instead complaining about that the value is missing.

In Report Viewer 10 (VS2010) this is actually working without any problems.

Anybody knows why this actually does not work with Report Viewer 11 (WinForms)?

Answer (score 1):

Set parameters right before you refresh report, it will work magically.
Don't know the reason since we can't debug it.

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramters);  
// do not put any other operation here           
reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

This is the first time for me to leave an answer, as I don't find this solution anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain v2012 had RDLC Schema changes, therefore I believe that you'd need to update the report with the correct schema. Not sure what all changed but it might help to change this for starters,

"xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"

I could be wrong but it appears on the surface that's at least the direction of your problem.